# Convert LightSwitch Desktop Application into LightSwitch Html Application

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a complete project in LighSwitch Desktop Application and I want to convert the complete application into LightSwitch Html Application.

So please guide me through the steps required to do this.

Thanks, in advance

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific way that you convert a Silverlight Desktop Client straight into a HTML Client. If you are using a later version of Visual Studio with Lightswitch installed, you may be able to add the HTML Client by right clicking on the project and selecting add client which would create the HTML client in your existing solution so you could access it's data.

If you were using an older project type then you may have to do an upgrade of the project which will occur when you open it in the later version of Visual Stuido. Please be aware though, this is a upgrade that cannot be rolled back so make sure you backup the project first. [More information here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh674025.aspx)

The latest version of Visual Studio Lightswitch will scaffold all of the screens accordingly for you, so providing you have a solid data layer the creating of all the screens required should be pretty painless. Obviously larger projects with custom controls may be a little more labourious and require extra work.

Good luck!

Comment: @anil, Paul is spot on. Your only option is to add an HTML client to the existing project, by right-clicking the LS project & selecting *Add HTML client*. If you don't see that option, then you'll be using an old version of VS 2012 & you'll need to upgrade VS first. But there's no way to convert your existing desktop **screens** though. Good luck!